# Reduce Complexity of Quicksort method

Tags: java, while-loop, complexity-theory, quicksort, partition

Hey guys I have a question I am trying to reduce the complexity of this code(at the bottom). My idea would be to remove the If clause in the while loop but I am kind of failing to do it. What I am trying to do here is compare two Elements of SortArray and Sort them with the Quicksort Algorithm. The Goal is to keep the Algorithm as simple as possible. Smaller and Bigger are the indices that walk through the array and switch if the element is bigger than the pivot. Bigger is at the end at the middle to get switched with the pivot.

```
   if (records.getElementAt(smaller).compareTo(Pivot) > 0 ) {


        swap(records, smaller, bigger);
        bigger--;

        }
```

My Idea was to combine the condition of the while loop and the if clause into one but that has not worked for me. I even tried two while loops with one being

```
 while (smaller <= bigger && records.getElementAt(smaller).compareTo(Pivot)>0
```

and the other

```
while (smaller <= bigger && records.getElementAt(smaller).compareTo(Pivot)<0
```

but that hasnt worked either.

```
import frame.SortArray;

public class QuickSortA extends QuickSort {

/**
 * Quicksort algorithm implementation to sort a SorrtArray by choosing the
 * pivot as the first (leftmost) element in the list
 * 
 * @param records
 *            - list of elements to be sorted as a SortArray
 * @param left
 *            - the index of the left bound for the algorithm
 * @param right
 *            - the index of the right bound for the algorithm
 * @return Returns the sorted list as SortArray
 */
@Override
public void Quicksort(SortArray records, int left, int right) {
    // TODO
    // implement the Quicksort A algorithm to sort the records
    // (choose the pivot as the first (leftmost) element in the list)
    if (left < right) {
    int a = Partition(records, left, right);
        Quicksort(records, left, a - 1);
        Quicksort(records, a + 1, right);
    }   

}   

public static int Partition(SortArray records, int left, int right) {

    int smaller = left + 1;
    int bigger  = right;
    SortingItem Pivot = records.getElementAt(left);


    while (smaller <= bigger ) {

        if (records.getElementAt(smaller).compareTo(Pivot) > 0 ) {


            swap(records, smaller, bigger);
            bigger--;

            }

        else

            smaller++;                
        }
    swap(records, bigger, left);    
    return bigger;





}

public static void swap(SortArray records, int small, int big) {
    SortingItem Tauschvariable;
    Tauschvariable = records.getElementAt(small);
    records.setElementAt(small, records.getElementAt(big));
    records.setElementAt(big, Tauschvariable);
}

// You may add additional methods here
```

}

```
public class SortArray {

private int numberOfItems;

private ArrayList<SortingItem> listOfItems;

private int readingOperations;
private int writingOperations;

/**
 * @param numberOfItems
 *            number of items to hold
 */
public SortArray(ArrayList<String[]> items) {
    numberOfItems = items.size();
    readingOperations = 0;
    writingOperations = 0;
    listOfItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String[] element : items) {
        SortingItem s = new SortingItem();
        s.BookSerialNumber = element[0];
        s.ReaderID = element[1];
        s.Status = element[2];
        listOfItems.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot make `quicksort#partition` not more efficient than O(n) (r - l) ...and you can't/should not combine the while conditions like that: because the orginal loops does something (esp. in regards of term. cond.), when the smaller element is greater than the pivot AND when lower(equal)!   ..in you approach, you run 2 (independent) sequences, one - where the smaller element is greater than pivot, the other one - where not ;) (one of them could be infinite!!:)

Comment: @xerx593 Hey Thanks for your answer! Okay I get your point that makes sense I have been trying that the last 20 minutes so you are saving me a lot of time. Do you think there is another way to reduce the complexity here? Anything could help! Currently one of the Tests i was given is failing it says: **complexity out of allowed range: O(n^2) required!**

Answer (score 0):

When it is correctly implemented, the average complexity of quicksort is O(NlogN).  The problem is that the worst-case complexity can be O(N^2), depending on how you select the partition.

The worst-case problem when the partitioning consistently splits the input subarray into 2 subarrays with drastically unequal sizes.  If you repeatedly split an N-sized array into arrays of size 1 and N - 1, then you end up doing N splits.  And since each partition step compares all N elements, you end up with N * O(N) comparisons; i.e. O(N^2).

Anyhow, the solution to the worst-case problem is to alter the way that you chose the pivot ... to try to avoid pathological behavior when the input is already sorted (or almost sorted).  Instead of picking the first element as the pivot you could:

- pick the pivot at random
- pick three pivot candidates from different parts of the array, and choose the middle one,
- etcetera

---

For the record, there is a mathematical proof that a comparison based sorting algorithm has a lower bound Ω(NlogN).

References:

- https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C you are probably right as the Test that is failing right now was always right even though the other 2 were wrong so I guess this input is already sorted! That helps me a  lot thanks!

Comment: I am supposed to choose the first element as the pivot though which makes things harder.

Comment: Another explanation could be that `swap` is not O(1).  For example, if SortArray's get and set operations are not O(1).   Is that possible?  Did you implement that class yourself?

Comment: I implemented swap myself but not SortArray. Everytime i access to the Array it adds in read and write operations. SortArray looks like this

Comment: Yet another possible explanation is that the test framework you are using is not estimating the complexity of your code correctly!  (Ask other students in your class if they are having this problem ...)

Comment: Good Idea. Hopefully its not me but the test framework! I'll try to ask other students.

Comment: Looks like it works for other people. I guess I have to give it another look but I cant find a way of reducing the complexity without changing the pivot.